# SeleniumWire PFX Certificate incompability

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, ssl-certificate, seleniumwire

I'm using seleniumwire + Undetected ChromeDriver and I need to use a PFX certificate in a website. But using this combo I don't get the popup to choose which certificate to use. In fact, it seems that none of my certificates are been recognized.
Here is the popup I'm used to:

[image]

That popup doesn't show anymore, and the website says I have no PFX Certificates installed (I have).